# Generating Static Documentation for Hybris Custom REST API

Tags: swagger, sap-commerce-cloud

As given @ https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/99783546e09949e2b4bf27795b889464.html 
 section for Generating Static Documentation, I tried to use the `ant wsStaticDoc` command to generate the static documnetation of the custom apis that have been created, it keeps failing with the below error. Can any one help me figure out how can I resolve this error:

> [artifact:mvn] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to     execute goal io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup-maven-plugin:1.2.0:convertSwagger2markup (default-cli) on project swagger-documentation: Execution default-cli of goal io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup-maven-plugin:1.2.0:convertSwagger2markup failed: Plugin io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup-maven-plugin:1.2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: nl.jworks.markdown_to_asciidoc:markdown_to_asciidoc:jar:1.0, ch.netzwerg:paleo-core:jar:0.10.1: Failure to find nl.jworks.markdown_to_asciidoc:markdown_to_asciidoc:jar:1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**:
markdown-to-asciidoc lib is not synced to Maven Central

Issue - https://github.com/bodiam/markdown-to-asciidoc/issues/26

Possible solution - https://github.com/bodiam/markdown-to-asciidoc/issues/26#issuecomment-371997400

`wsStaticDoc` task uses maven plugins under the hood to generate documentation.

```
        <artifact:mvn pom="@{templateDir}/pom.xml" fork="true" failonerror="true" mavenVersion="3.2.5">
            <arg value="io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup-maven-plugin:convertSwagger2markup" />
            <arg value="org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-maven-plugin:process-asciidoc" />
            <arg value="-Dswagger.input=@{swaggerInput}" />
            <arg value="-Ddoc.generated=@{tempDir}" />
            <arg value="-Dasciidoctor.input.directory=@{templateDir}/asciidoc" />
            <arg value="-Ddoc.output=@{outputDir}" />
            <jvmarg line="${env.MAVEN_OPTS} ${env.JAVA_OPTS}" />
        </artifact:mvn>
```

Unresolved artifact actually is available (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ca/szc/thirdparty/nl/jworks/markdown_to_asciidoc/markdown_to_asciidoc/1.0/)
Most probably, you are having some network issues with maven central.

Do you have specific settings at ~/.m2/settings.xml?

Comment: I do seem to find any .m2 folder on my machine.:(

Comment: Make sure that your file editor shows hidden files.
Anyway, the real reason why it doesn't work for you described here - https://github.com/bodiam/markdown-to-asciidoc/issues/26

Check comment https://github.com/bodiam/markdown-to-asciidoc/issues/26#issuecomment-371997400 for a possible solution.